# IOS: How to update the notification permission to request one new option that wasn't requested before?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, ios-permissions

I have an app that already requested user permission for notifications before with the following 3 options:

- UNAuthorizationOptionBadge
- UNAuthorizationOptionSound
- UNAuthorizationOptionAlert

[image: notification permission]

Now I want to push an update for the app that requests one more option for the same permission which is `UNAuthorizationOptionCriticalAlert`

I'm using this code:-

```
UNAuthorizationOptions options = ( UNAuthorizationOptionBadge | UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionCriticalAlert);
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:options completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *_Nullable error) {
      if (!granted) {
        NSLog(@"Something To Print3");
        return;
      }
    }];
```

However the OS doesn't ask the user for the new option because it thinks that this permission has already been granted before. granted in the above example is already true. I tried removing the 3 old permissions but I get the same result.

How can I make the OS request the new option `UNAuthorizationOptionCriticalAlert`?

Comment: If permissions have already been requested then you will need to display an alert yourself that request the user to go in to your app's settings and enable the additional permission

Comment: The permission has been requested and granted before but I want to add a new option to the permission. No other way than directing the users to settings?

Comment: Nope.  Once the permissions request has been shown by iOS and the user has responded, iOS won't show it again, even if you are asking for additional options